# How can I run a flutter app on an iOS Simulator

Tags: flutter, flutter-ios

I have been working on an app recently. I tested on the android emulator and it worked perfectly. However, when I test on an iOS simulator, I get this error:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 8 in debug mode...
/Users/george/Desktop/builds/fastex_2/ios/Runner/Info.plist: Property List error: Found non-key inside <dict> at line 42 / JSON error: JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set. around line 1, column 0.
CocoaPods' output:
↳
      Preparing
    Analyzing dependencies
    Inspecting targets to integrate
      Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (`$(ARCHS_STANDARD)`, `arm64`)
    Finding Podfile changes
      - Flutter
      - cloud_firestore
      - connectivity
      - firebase_auth
      - firebase_core
      - flutter_secure_storage
      - fluttertoast
      - google_maps_flutter
      - path_provider_ios
      - shared_preferences_ios
      - url_launcher_ios
      - webview_flutter_wkwebview
    Fetching external sources
    -> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
    -> Fetching podspec for `cloud_firestore` from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`
    cloud_firestore: Using Firebase SDK version '8.9.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `connectivity` from `.symlinks/plugins/connectivity/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_auth` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`
    firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '8.9.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_core` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`
    firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '8.9.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `flutter_secure_storage` from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_secure_storage/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `fluttertoast` from `.symlinks/plugins/fluttertoast/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `google_maps_flutter` from `.symlinks/plugins/google_maps_flutter/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `path_provider_ios` from `.symlinks/plugins/path_provider_ios/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `shared_preferences_ios` from `.symlinks/plugins/shared_preferences_ios/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `url_launcher_ios` from `.symlinks/plugins/url_launcher_ios/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `webview_flutter_wkwebview` from `.symlinks/plugins/webview_flutter_wkwebview/ios`
    Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
      CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_0_3_5.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/8.10.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/8.9.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_c_7_9.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/c/7/9/Reachability/3.2/Reachability.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/8.9.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/8.9.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_5_1_0.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/5/1/0/Toast/4.0.0/Toast.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_a_d_d.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/a/d/d/GoogleMaps/6.0.1/GoogleMaps.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_6_3_6.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/6/3/6/FirebaseAuth/8.10.0/FirebaseAuth.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_8_b_d.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/8/b/d/FirebaseCore/8.10.0/FirebaseCore.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/5/1/0/Toast/4.0.0/Toast.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_0_9_f.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/9/f/FirebaseFirestore/8.10.0/FirebaseFirestore.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/a/d/d/GoogleMaps/6.0.1/GoogleMaps.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/a/d/d/GoogleMaps/6.0.1/GoogleMaps.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/c/7/9/Reachability/3.2/Reachability.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/6/3/6/FirebaseAuth/8.9.0/FirebaseAuth.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_0_8_4.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/7.7.0/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/7.7.0/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/7.7.0/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_c_e_3.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/c/e/3/GTMSessionFetcher/1.7.0/GTMSessionFetcher.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/c/e/3/GTMSessionFetcher/1.7.0/GTMSessionFetcher.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/8/b/d/FirebaseCore/8.9.0/FirebaseCore.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/7.7.0/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_8_3_c.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/8/3/c/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics/8.10.0/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/8/b/d/FirebaseCore/8.9.0/FirebaseCore.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/a/d/d/GoogleMaps/6.0.1/GoogleMaps.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/7.7.0/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/7.7.0/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/7.7.0/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_0_b_5.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/b/5/PromisesObjC/2.0.0/PromisesObjC.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/a/d/d/GoogleMaps/6.0.1/GoogleMaps.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
    [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "GoogleMaps/Base":
      In Podfile:
        google_maps_flutter (from `.symlinks/plugins/google_maps_flutter/ios`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
          GoogleMaps was resolved to 6.0.1, which depends on
            GoogleMaps/Maps (= 6.0.1) was resolved to 6.0.1, which depends on
              GoogleMaps/Base (= 6.0.1)
    Specs satisfying the `GoogleMaps/Base (= 6.0.1)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:317:in `raise_error_unless_state'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:299:in `block in unwind_for_conflict'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:297:in `tap'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:297:in `unwind_for_conflict'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:682:in `attempt_to_activate'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:254:in `process_topmost_state'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:182:in `resolve'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in `resolve'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:94:in `resolve'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1078:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1076:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in `analyze'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:416:in `analyze'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:241:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:240:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:161:in `install!'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 8.
Exited (sigterm)
```

This is the content of my Podfile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

# post_install do |installer|
#   installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
#     flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
#   end
# end

post_install do |installer_representation|
  installer_representation.project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ARCHS'] = 'armv7 armv7s'
    end
  end
end
```

I tried changing the platform version several times from 8.0 to 15.0 but I still get this error.

Please help if you have resolved a similar problem. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**Just go to the file your_project -> ios -> Podfile**

at the end of the Podfile just add below lines

```
post_install do |installer_representation|
  installer_representation.project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ARCHS'] = 'armv7 armv7s'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Still had an error

Comment: Did u try with actual device ?

Comment: no... i'm using ios Simulator for iPhone 8